# How to verify if an iOS sandbox account is valid still?

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, storekit

I'm having some issues with sandbox users. According to Apple's docs

> Important: If you mistakenly use a sandbox tester account to sign in to a production environment, like iTunes, on your test device instead of your test environment, the sandbox account becomes invalid and can’t be used again. If this happens, create a new sandbox tester account with a new email address.

In my case I haven't tried to login to the production environment with these accounts, but am still getting the invalidated somehow. It seems they will be good for a day or two, and for the first couple purchases and then stop working.

I'm getting back `SKErrorDomain Code: 0 NSLocalizedDescription: Cannot connect to iTunes Store`most times when I try to purchase.

Most recently I even got "You are not authorized to make purchases of this InApp Purchase in Sandbox at this time. [Environment: Sandbox]"

I'm very flustered by these errors because it seems that it will work fine and then intermittently stop working. Has anyone found a way to successfully verify if an account is invalid, or found a way to get past these issues?

Comment: We are experiencing errors with the sandbox environment now, all purchases fail on different stages (sometimes they just time out). That happens for all our apps (on different dev teams). Seems like iTunes is having a problem there, yesterday it was all working.

Answer (score 1):

Each time I run into this problem, these steps typically clear it:

1. Make sure phone is signed out of all services (iCloud, App Store, everything)
2. Restart the phone.
3. Remove the app from phone and re-install via Xcode
4. When the app prompts for credentials during in-app purchase, enter sandbox credentials.

There is the very off chance that the sandbox account must accept some new terms from Apple. Log-into developer.apple.com and make sure you don't have any lingering alerts for that account.

Best of luck!